# Creating a new website

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

I am trying to create a new website from the backend under System > Manage stores. Can someone walk me through the process of getting this set up or point me to a tutorial that works? I have tried several tutorials, but none have worked. My problem is editing the index.php file and the .htaccess file. Each tutorial has told me different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a tutorial that contains information on how to setup multiple store fronts on one Magento installation at:

http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-store-fronts-with-magento/

Answer (score 2):

Found my mistakes.

This tutorial worked for me.

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/

My error was a simple typo in the file path directory for mage.php

Answer (score 0):

very simple you can install theme with two different ways
From admin panel and from FTP.
if you are installing from Magento Admin then follow these simple steps:

https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/magento/how-to-install-magento-themes

if you are installing from FTP then before uploading any file must be compler option should be (off) in under system option. and then upload your package file from FTP on main folder.